# Linkedin API: Looking for the most effective way to search a large list of people

Tags: javascript, optimization, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to find the most optimal way to search a list of names in LinkedIn. For example if one has a list of 150 peoples and not to hit the throttle limit of 100, the requests must be combined somehow. So far I have come up with the following syntax using the JavaScript API:

```
IN.API.PeopleSearch()
    .fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", "positions", ...)
    .params({
        "first-name": firstname1 OR firstname2 OR firstname3, 
        "last-name": lastname1 OR lastname2 OR lastname3
        ...
    })
```

Which works, in a way, but with this search, following problems arise:

1. "John Smith" and "Juan Carlos" would also return "John Carlos" and "Juan Smith". Which means that the response is getting larger and larger with more names searched at a time and needs more requests to get the whole list of results. This data also needs to be processed to filter out undesirable results. Which is not a problem, but could use unnecessary amount of requests if there is a better solution.
2. Because of the first problem the people should be searched by a group of some reasonable amount - somewhere let's say 3-10 people.

With a list of 150 people my current solution would probably be enough, but in case something goes wrong and the same list needs to be searched again, then the limit would probably be already reached and it's not possible to search the same list again before tomorrow.

Is there a better solution, that I haven't found yet, to optimise the number of requests?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to check if it works, but I suggest to try using `keywords` param instead of `first-name` and `last-name`.

According to [documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api), `keywords` params matches:

> Members who have **all** the keywords anywhere in their profile. Use this field when you don't know how to more accurately map the input to a more specific parameter. (Don't forget to URL encode this data.)

If `OR` operator works in parameters' values, it looks like searching this way:

```
IN.API
.PeopleSearch()
.fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", "positions", ...)
.params({
    "keywords": "firstname1%20lastname1" OR "firstname2%20lastname2" (etc...) 
})
```

should do what you want.

Of course, this methods also has it's downsides (e.g. you may get irrelevant results - people who just *mentioned* the name you search for in their profiles), but this should be even easier to filter than your method.

*Note:* documentation (linked above) encourages searching for people this way (as an alternative):

> If you have a full name, such as Andrew Clark, and don't know how to best split it into first-name and last-name fields, pass it in as a keyword instead.

Comment: Uh. Just tested that and it looks like (at least for non-premium account) keywords search retrieves only people with 1st or 2nd degree connection. This is probably not what you want, but I'll leave my answer here for you to check it yourself :)

Comment: Thank  you for the time and answer. But indeed, the downside is, as you already mentioned, only first and second degree connections are returned.